# Disable single pages and archives and keep preview

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives, single, previews

**TL;DR**

Does anybody know how I can disable single pages and archives for custom post types while keeping the preview mode?

---

I'm looking for a way to disable the single and archive pages for a custom post type, because the posts will only be shown in the archive of a custom taxonomy that is assigned to the posts. This would usually be easily achieved by setting `'publicly_queryable'  => false` while creating the CPT.

Now, here's the twist: I still want to be able to use the preview mode for the posts, so I can check my changes on the post before I save them. Since setting `'publicly_queryable'  => false` will also disable the preview page I'm stuck between having single pages as duplicate content or not being able to see the drafts or changes of posts.

---

Based on the answer from Cesar (thanks!) I'm using following solution, which also shows how to keep the preview mode and redirects to the archive of the taxonomy, as explained above.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect', 99);

function post_redirect()
{
    global $post;
    if ((is_post_type_archive('post_type') || is_singular('post_type')) && !is_preview())
    {
        $post_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy');
        if($post_term = $post_terms[0])
        {
            wp_redirect(get_term_link($post_term->term_id) . '#' . $post->post_name, 301);
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm still interested in a solution without redirects, in case thats possible.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect, when someone tries to see the `archive` or the `single` of your custom post type, just redirect them to another page, just put this in your **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'theme_redirects', 99 );

function theme_redirects() {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'post_type_slug' ) || is_singular( 'post_type_slug' ) ) {
     wp_redirect( 'my_url' );
         die();
  }
}
```

See references:

[is_post_type_archive](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive)

[is_singular](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

[template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it would work. I'd rather not use redirects though. I'll leave the question open for a while in case someone comes around with a solution without redirects. Otherwise I'll accept it.