# Override default post type 'post'

Tags: posts

I am trying to disable the archive page and the single page for the default post type 'post'.

So far I have tried multiple methods:

```
function my_func() {
    if ( post_type_exists( 'post' ) ) {
        global $wp_post_types;
        $wp_post_types['post']->publicly_queryable = false;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_func', 99 );

function change_default_post(){
    $post_type = 'post';
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object('post');
    $post_type_object->has_archive = false;
    $post_type_object->public = false;
    $post_type_object->publicly_queryable = false;

    register_post_type($post_type, $post_type_object);
}

add_action( 'init', 'change_default_post' );

function change_default_post(){
    $object = get_post_type_object('post');
    $object->has_archive = false;
    $object->public = false;
}

add_action( 'init', 'change_default_post' );
```

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/273902)? redirecting when someone tries to visit either of these pages

Comment: It would be simpler to simply remove permissions to create posts from all users, then you won't have anything post-related accessible from the front or back end. Any particular reason you're trying to modify the actual post type?

Comment: I have a theme with demo content posts. I have already modified it with a child theme, and the role that the posts have are now replaced with a custom post type. I am currently testing the WP Super Cache plugin (preloading pages) and just realized how many post types have single pages enabled, that i don't need. It's not a problem disabling them for my or the theme-s custom post types. **The question is:** if I use a redirect or just delete all demo posts, and disable adding new 'post' posts, will WP Super Cache still cache a page?